# Superposition of two same energy levels

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, harmonic-oscillator, eigenvalue

Spatial part of the ground state energy eigenfunction for a quantum particle confined
to one dimension with a harmonic oscillator potential energy is given by:

$u_0(x)=(\frac{m\omega}{\pi \hbar})^{1/4} \exp(- \frac{m\omega }{2\hbar} x^2)$

If we have the same particle in the same system at $t=0$ given by:

$\psi(x,0)=(\frac{m\omega}{\pi \hbar})^{1/4} \exp(-2 \frac{m\omega }{2\hbar} x^2)$

This is essentially a superposition of two ground state energy eigenfucntion?

So can you have a superposition of two same energy levels or am i interpreting something wrong?

Comment: $e^{-2A}$ is not $e^{-A}+e^{-A}$ .

Comment: $\psi$ doesn’t look properly normalized.

Answer (score 1):

Function $\psi(x,0)$ is not the ground state of the oscillator, as can be checked by a direct substitution. It is a superposition of many oscillator states, and can be expanded in terms of these states using usual projection procedures.